# How do I combine two Lucene queries using OR?

Tags: java, lucene

I'd like to search my index on two fields called "a" and "b".  I am given searches like `Freud -- theories of psychology` and I'd like to perform the following query:

```
(a="Freud" AND b="theories of psychology") OR (b="Freud" AND a="theories of psychology")
```

How do I do this?  So far I have Lucene constructing the two halves (`firstHalf` and `secondHalf`) using `MultiFieldQueryParser`, then I've combined them with

```
BooleanQuery combined = new BooleanQuery();
combined.add(firstHalf, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
combined.add(secondHalf, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

But `combined` allows results to be returned where only "theories" is found and not "psychology", where I definitely want both terms.  It seems like Lucene is splitting "theories of psychology" into three words and combining them individually with OR.  How do I prevent this?

`firstHalf` looks like:

```
Query firstHalf = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(Version.LUCENE_33,
         new String[]{"Freud", "theories of psychology"},
         new String[]{"a", "b"},
         new BooleanClause.Occur[]{BooleanClause.Occur.MUST, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST},
         analyzer);
```

where `analyzer` is just a `StandardAnalyzer` object.

Comment: Was just told that Lucene doesn't support Boolean logic like this, and that SHOULD != OR.  In that case, _Lucene in Action_ 2nd Edition is wrong on page 95. :)  So now I know _why_ my query is broken, just don't know how to fix it still.

Comment: Are you sure the query is correct? The query `theories of psychology` means at least one of the three words must occur somewhere, but none of them is a required word.

Comment: @KaiChan Nope, I had to modify this to put that restriction in.  I think I got it though. :)

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out myself, but now the code is significantly longer; if anyone knows a more elegant solution, please post and I'll gladly reward. :)  (Although I'll be making this into a method shortly...but here's the full version of what's going on...)

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_33, "a", analyzer);
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
Query a_0 = parser.parse("Freud");
parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_33, "b", analyzer);
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
Query b_1 = parser.parse("theories of psychology");

BooleanQuery firstHalf = new BooleanQuery();
firstHalf.add(a_0, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
firstHalf.add(b_1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_33, "b", analyzer);
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
Query b_0 = parser.parse("Freud");
parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_33, "a", analyzer);
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
Query a_1 = parser.parse("theories of psychology");

BooleanQuery secondHalf = new BooleanQuery();
secondHalf.add(b_0, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
secondHalf.add(a_1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

BooleanQuery combined = new BooleanQuery();
combined.add(firstHalf, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
combined.add(secondHalf, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

Turns out `SHOULD` does work the way I need it to here.  Hopefully someone finds this helpful and I'm not just talking to myself in public ;)

Comment: It's my recent experience that in learning Lucene, you should avoid QueryParser and try to piece everything together from the direct underlying Query types. You'll get a better understanding of Lucene and won't get distracted by query syntax. As Xodarap mentions, what you really want here is PhraseQuery. What you have now will match documents with "theories" "of" "psychology" in any order or position, not the exact phrase. (Actually, StandardAnalyzer will filter out "of", so even PhraseQuery won't match your exact phrase...but that's a limitation of search we usually live just accept.)

Answer (score 2):

Standard analyzer will tokenize. So the query `theories of psychology` is equivalent to `theories OR of OR psychology`.

If you want to search for the phrase "theories of psychology" use a [PhraseQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html), or else note that the default QueryParser will interpret quotes as meaning a phrase (i.e. change your code to be `"\"theories of psychology\""`).

And yes, there is a sense in which Lucene doesn't use Boolean logic, but it's technical and not really relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote below class to generate chained fuzzy queries where a term has to be searched over multiple fields.
Combined query can be retrieved by calling `GetQuery()` method.

```
public class QueryParam
{
    public string[] Fields { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }

    private QueryParam _andOperandSuffix;
    private QueryParam _orOperandSuffix;

    private readonly BooleanQuery _indexerQuery = new BooleanQuery();        

    public QueryParam(string term, params string[] fields)
    {
        Term = term;
        Fields = fields;
    }

    public QueryParam And(QueryParam queryParam)
    {
        _andOperandSuffix = queryParam;
        return this;
    }

    public QueryParam Or(QueryParam queryParam)
    {
        _orOperandSuffix = queryParam;
        return this;
    }

    public BooleanQuery GetQuery()
    {            
        foreach (var field in Fields)
            _indexerQuery.Add(new FuzzyQuery(new Term(field, Term)), Occur.SHOULD);

        if (_andOperandSuffix != null)
            _indexerQuery.Add(_andOperandSuffix.GetQuery(),Occur.MUST);

        if (_orOperandSuffix != null)
            _indexerQuery.Add(_orOperandSuffix.GetQuery(), Occur.SHOULD);

        return _indexerQuery;
    }

}
```

Example:

```
var leftquery = new QueryParam("Freud", "a").And(new QueryParam("theories of psychology", "b"));
var rightquery = new QueryParam("Freud", "b").And(new QueryParam("theories of psychology", "a"));
var query = leftquery.Or(rightquery);
```